# nginx proxy pass preserving URL

Tags: nginx, proxy, reverse-proxy, proxypass

I've implemented a proxy_pass rule in nginx and it's works just with some links. My rule is:

```
server_name www.example.com

location ~ /en/(.*)$ {
        resolver 8.8.8.8;
        proxy_pass http://www.destinyweb.en/$1;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }
```

My purpose is to type "www.example.com/en/index.jsp" and the proxy_pass redirect my request to "www.destinyweb.en/index.jsp".

It's working well when the links in the targeted web is like "index.jsp" but is not working when the link is like "/index.jsp" (with a slash before the index.jsp). Some of the links have "/" before the file targeted and other doesn't have.

When the content of the website is like this works well:

```
<a href="index.jsp">Hello</a>
```

When the content of the website is like this DOES NOT work:

```
<a href="/index.jsp">Hello</a>
```

Some of you know some regex to parser this "/"?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to include the `/` in the `location` regex match. So something like:

```
location ~ ^/en(/.*)?$ {
```

would match with or without the leading slash. You'd also modify the `proxy_pass` line like so:

```
proxy_pass http://www.destinyweb.en$1;
```

since the $1 would include or not include the `/` as the original request did.